# Variables in makefile causes unexpected end of file when brackets exist

Tags: makefile, cygwin, ksh, mks

I am getting `syntax error: unexpected end of file` when I run make clean.

I was successful of getting rid of that error when I removed the brackets around the variable that was causing the error.

I want to know why does this happen.

I am using:

- Windows XP SP2 64 bit
- CYGWIN
- KSH R48

My variable is called `TARGET` and is like this but way longer:

`./ShowEnumContentsPrefAPI.o ./ShowEnumsPrefAPI.o`

The line where the error happens was:

`rm -f $(TARGET)`

When I removed the brackets the error was gone and it worked:

`rm -f $TARGET`

Another line as well was:

`if [ "$(TARGET)" != "" ]; then \`

When I removed the brackets the error was gone and it worked:

`if [ "$TARGET" != "" ]; then \`

==============================================================

- What is happening here?
- How can I prevent this from happening without changing every line that is causing the error (I have more than 1000 line in this makefile)?
- How did this work on `mks 5.2 sh.exe` and will not work on `cygwin ksh`?

==============================================================

**UPDATE:**

This is the actual code:

```
clean:
    if [ "$TARGET" != "" ]; then \
        rm -rf $(TARGET); \
    fi
```

This is what produced the error `syntax error: unexpected end of file`:

```
clean:
    if [ "$(TARGET)" != "" ]; then \
        rm -rf $(TARGET); \
    fi
```

The only difference is the brackets around target.

---

Doing the

```
echo "T:$T"; \
echo "TARGET:$TARGET"; \
```

Produced

```
T:
TARGET:ARGET
```

---

`echo "(TARGET):$(TARGET)";\` produced the `syntax error: unexpected end of file` again.

---

Today I tried cutting off some of the TARGET variable. Making it shorter by hand intentionally and the `rm -f $(TARGET)` worked fine. I suspect it's a problem with cygwin's `rm`, `[` exes. I will try upgrading to cygwin's latest version and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you assigned a value to `$T` instead of `$(TARGET)`

Unlike bash, in make the `$` only applies to the next character or bracketted expression.  Thus '`$TARGET`' resolves to the expansion of '`$T`' plus the literal '`ARGET`'...  To illustrate, consider the following:

```
X := _X_
XX := _YY_
$(info - $XX -)
$(info - $(XX) -)
```

you get:

```
- _X_X -
- _YY_ -
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get what you are saying. But what happens to me is the opposite I guess. And what makes it weirder is that I use $() elsewhere in the file and it works fine. Thanks a lot tho.

Comment: You'll have to post a more complete code -- specifically how TARGET is set, and some more context around where it is referenced (I'm assuming it's in a recipe.  If it's in a shell script called outside of the Makefile, however, then it's a totally different issue).

Comment: Yes it is in a recipe. I am sorry, I will be updating the question as soon as I can. Thanks for help.

Comment: You may also want to try adding the line: `echo "T:$T TARGET:$TARGET (TARGET):$(TARGET)"` into your recipe to see what it's expanding to.

Comment: You still didn't put the code where you set $(TARGET)';   However, if  `$(TARGET)` includes a mismatched quote, then you would get the behavior you're describing (except the rm line would cause an issue in that case...).  Do an `$(info $(TARGET))` in your makefile, which will output `$(TARGET)`, including the quotes.

Comment: I tried some modifications today. Check my last edit!